# Select first existing row with equal or greater value

Tags: python, pandas

```
df

     A    B        C
0  500  515     Jack
1  510  515    Helen
2  520  515  Mathiew
3  530  515   Jordan
```

I want to get a new `df1` with next conditions:

- Select the rows where *A = B*.
- If it doesn´t exist any row where *A = B*, select the first existing row where *A > B*.

In this case, `df1` should be:

```
     A    B        C
2  520  515  Mathiew
```

I´ve tried:

```
df1 = df[df["A"] == df["B"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if at least one equal row by [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) and then filter by your solution, if not, get [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for index of max value (necessary unique index values):

```
if (df["A"] == df["B"]).any():
    df1 = df[df["A"] == df["B"]]
else:
    df1 = df.loc[[(df["A"] > df["B"]).idxmax()]]
```

Alternative is select first row by `iloc`:

```
if (df["A"] == df["B"]).any():
    df1 = df[df["A"] == df["B"]]
else:
    df1 = df.loc[(df["A"] > df["B"])].iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the structure of `df` so I will assume it is an list of dicts

```
df1 = [row for row in df if row["a"] == row["b"]]
if len(df1) == 0:
    for row in df:
        if row["a"] > row["b"]:
            df1.append(row)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (df["A"] == df["B"]).sum() == 0:
    first_bigger = (df["A"] > df["B"]).idxmax()
    new_df = df.iloc[first_bigger : first_bigger+1]
else: 
    new_df = df[df["A"] == df["B"]]
new_df
```

If `if (df["A"] == df["B"]).sum()` is equal to zero, that means no two items are equal,  `(df["A"] > df["B"]).idxmax()` return the first occurrence where  A is bigger than B.